# Mvc Dropdownlist postback value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get the value from dropdownlist into my controller but I keep getting value 0.

I want to perform sorting function when a user selects the value from dropdownlist. Postback is working but when i select value from dropdownlist I just keep getting 0 not 1 or 2. Am i doing it right ? or should i define this in my controller ?

Sorry but I'm just a beginner.

**Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Products(int page = 1, int pageSize = 9)
    {   
        Shopping db = new Shopping();
        List<Product> listProducts = db.Products.ToList();
        PagedList<Product> model = new PagedList<Product>(listProducts, page, pageSize);
        return View(model);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Products(int? sortBy, int page = 1, int pageSize = 9)
    {
        sortBy = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["OrderBy"]);
        switch (sortBy)
        {
            case 1:
                List<Product> listProductsasc = db.Products.OrderBy(p=>p.Name).ToList();
                PagedList<Product> modelasc = new PagedList<Product>(listProductsasc, page, pageSize);
                return View(modelasc);
            case 2:
                List<Product> listProductsdesc = db.Products.OrderByDescending(p=>p.Name).ToList();
                PagedList<Product> modeldesc = new PagedList<Product>(listProductsdesc, page, pageSize);
                return View(modeldesc);
            default:
                List<Product> listProducts = db.Products.ToList();
                PagedList<Product> model = new PagedList<Product>(listProducts, page, pageSize);
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            Sort by:
            @Html.DropDownList("OrderBy", new List<SelectListItem>

             {
                new SelectListItem{ Text="A-Z", Value = "1" },
                new SelectListItem{ Text="Z-A", Value = "2" }
             }, "-- Order By --" , new { onchange = "document.getElementById('Form1').submit();" })

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Products", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Form1" }))
            { 
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Filter" />
                </div>
            </div>
            }
        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your dropdownlist is outside the form tags, so it never posts back its value. Move it to inside the `@using (Html.BeginForm()) { .... }`

Side note, You can just add a parameter `int orderBy` to your method and it will be correctly bound. You should also consider making the form `FormMethod.Get` and deleting the POST method unless there is a particular reason your need to make a POST

Comment: yeah i mage it to FormMethod.Get. it is working now. Actually I've used PagedList.Mvc. After selecting OrderBy, it sorts fine but when I click to next page it doesn't show sorted items anymore.

Comment: Thats because you not persisting the `orderby` value. You should ask a new question and show the code in the view where you generate the `PagedList` (and you will find this far easier if your use a view model with property `int OrderBy` and `PagedList<Product> products` and strongly bind to your view model so the `DropDownList` maintains its value when you return the view.

Comment: Note also you should remove the `new { onchange ....` in the `DropDownList()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to insert your

```
@Html.DropDownList("OrderBy", new List<SelectListItem>
{
     new SelectListItem{ Text="A-Z", Value = "1" },
     new SelectListItem{ Text="Z-A", Value = "2" }
},
```

into your `@Html.BeginForm()` like

```
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Products", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Form1" }))
            { 
<div class="col-sm-4">
            Sort by:
            @Html.DropDownList("OrderBy", new List<SelectListItem>

             {
                new SelectListItem{ Text="A-Z", Value = "1" },
                new SelectListItem{ Text="Z-A", Value = "2" }
             }, "-- Order By --" , new { onchange = "document.getElementById('Form1').submit();" })

        </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Filter" />
                </div>
            </div>
            }
        </div>
```

And for addition.You don't need to Use `Request.Form["OrderBy"]`,change your parameter name and method like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Products(int orderyBy, int page = 1, int pageSize = 9)
{
     switch (orderyBy)
     {
         case 1:
             List<Product> listProductsasc = db.Products.OrderBy(p=>p.Name).ToList();
             PagedList<Product> modelasc = new PagedList<Product>(listProductsasc, page, pageSize);
             return View(modelasc);
         case 2:
             List<Product> listProductsdesc = db.Products.OrderByDescending(p=>p.Name).ToList();
             PagedList<Product> modeldesc = new PagedList<Product>(listProductsdesc, page, pageSize);
             return View(modeldesc);
         default:
             List<Product> listProducts = db.Products.ToList();
             PagedList<Product> model = new PagedList<Product>(listProducts, page, pageSize);
             return View(model);
     }
 }
```

When you Post your form it's elements with name/value pair coming into your method's parameters and assign them by their name

Comment: yeah i mage it to FormMethod.Get. it is working now. Actually I've used PagedList.Mvc. After selecting OrderBy, it sorts fine but when I click to next page it doesn't show sorted items anymore.

Comment: try to debug you code,because I can't debug it from my place.If it doesn't sort, the problem is in your switch statement's cases.Debug and see if it orders your items in listProductasc and listProductdesc variables